# ChromeDriver opens sites only with valid SSL certs

Tags: ssl, https, webdriver, ssl-certificate, selenium-chromedriver

There are two instances of the same site, only difference is, that one uses a valid, another one uses an invalid `HTTPS/SSL certification`. I tried to open both in headless `ChromeDriver 2.31` and found it opens site only with valid `SSL` certification.

```
<chromepath> --headless --remote-debugging-port=9101 --disable-gpu <siteurl>
```

Code above opens a site https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/identification_number with a preview from the given website.

I use this to ignore certificate problems, but I get the same blank page for this site in `ChromeDriver`.

```
caps.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--ignore-certificate-errors"));
```

Comment: DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       
handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, false) try this

Comment: @iamsankalp89 : I tried your code with value true too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok Dear we will try other solutio

Comment: @iamsankalp89 : I get `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` during debugging.

Comment: Try the updated code is working in MY pc

Comment: is your problem is solved?

Comment: @iamsankalp89 : No, I tried to take a screenshot too from this site and got a blank screen. So it is still not working. I used this code:
        `File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\screenshot.png"));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153655/discussion-between-iamsankalp89-and-plaidshirt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `DesiredCapabilities`

```
DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ();       
handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, false);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (handlSSLErr);
```

Try it, may be it helps you.

Second way:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions option= new ChromeOptions();
option.addArguments("headless");
option.addArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
WebDriver d=new ChromeDriver(option);
//d.get("http://expired.badssl.com/");
d.get("https://expired.badssl.com/");
```

Image for reference [image]

Comment: Could you please try it in headless mode too?

Comment: Could you share whole code? It is not working for me in headless mode.

Comment: Problem is still persist. It doesn't work for `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` errors.

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, maybe it is useful to someone, the below parameter works for me.

```
acceptInsecureCerts: true
```

Comment: Could you suggest the working combination of a) chrome driver version b) selenium version c)chrome browser version? I am using Chrome driver version: 2.44, Selenium Version: 2.42, Chrome browser Version 70.0. It opens and releases the connection (ie.closes window) at once in selenium. In manual, I am getting error, NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, able to visit by accepting warning! If possible, piece of working code, please!